# Drag API Function Not Working With Javascript Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, this, arrow-functions

I've done my best to find this question already being asking but came up empty handed so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

In short, I've written a factory function to help me with some drag & drop functionality in a project I'm working on, but am seeing different behavior depending on how I write some of the methods inside of it.

Here's the code in total:

```
  const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(draggablesSelectors);
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll(containersSelectors);

  draggables.forEach(draggableEl => {
    draggableEl.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart, false);
    draggableEl.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd, false);
  });

  function dragStart() {
    console.log("drag start");
  }

  function dragEnd() {
    console.log("drag end");
  }

  const returnDraggables = () => {
    return draggables;
  }

  const returnContainers = () => {
    return containers;
  }

  return {returnDraggables, returnContainers};
}

const draggableEls = Draggable(".ship", ".gameboard");
```

I know using arrow functions changes the lexical scope of `this`, but what I could use some help understanding is why I'll see "drag start" and "drag end" in the console when I write the `dragStart` and `dragEnd` functions the way they are above, but when I write them as arrow functions they don't do anything.

Thanks very much!

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @kikon for helping me realize I had the function declarations after the forEach loop. Once I moved things into the correct order (shown below) everything is working great.

````
  const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(draggablesSelectors);
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll(containersSelectors);

  // Draggables Functions
  const dragStart = () => {
    console.log("drag start");
  }

  const dragEnd = () => {
    console.log("drag end");
  }

  const dragDrop = () => {
    console.log("drop");
  }

  // Container Functions
  const dragOver = () => {
    console.log("drag over");
  }

  const dragEnter = () => {
    console.log("drag enter");
  }

  const dragLeave = () => {
    console.log("drag leave");
  }

  const returnDraggables = () => {
    return draggables;
  }

  const returnContainers = () => {
    return containers;
  }

  draggables.forEach(draggableEl => {
    draggableEl.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart, false);
    draggableEl.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd, false);
    draggableEl.addEventListener("drop", dragDrop, false);
  });

  containers.forEach(containerEl => {
    containerEl.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver, false);
    containerEl.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter, false);
    containerEl.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave, false);
  });

  return {returnDraggables, returnContainers};
}

const draggableEls = Draggable(".ship", ".gameboard");
console.log(draggableEls.returnDraggables());
export default Draggable;```
````

Comment: Are you calling `returnDraggables` and `returnContainers` anywhere? Note also that they _return_ a value, they don't log anything like the other function declarations do. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Hey @Andy, I'm not currently calling them anywhere. I haven't encountered that being an issue on other factory functions, but I've definitely been bitten by things of this sort before so it's worth trying.

Comment: I tried it with arrow functions and it works. But of course, you have to declare `const`s before the `.forEach` since only function declarations are hoisted. Still, I assume you did that, otherwise you'd have a `ReferenceError`. Please add the exact version that doesn't work.

Comment: @kikon, thank you. I wasn't thinking and had the arrow function declarations *below* my `forEach` loop which is why they weren't working but the regular function declarations were — just as you had said. I'm not seeing the option to accept your answer but will as soon as I do. Thanks again!

Comment: For posterity, I've updated the question above to show the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cause might be the fact that you declare/define the handlers `dragStart` and `dragEnd` after they are used in the `forEach` loop.

That works with functions, as they are hoisted, but not with `var`s or `const`s. Still, if you used `const`, as for the other arrow functions, you
should have got a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out the order of things @kikon, this was the issue. I clearly wasn't thinking straight at the time so I appreciate you helping me realize what the issue was.